# Tomcat request URL

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

We have an issue with java web application hosted on a tomcat server.

The tomcat instance runs on with the following setting:

```
<Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

In the application, links use getContextPath method, which returns links such as:
http://localhost:8090/webapp

However, when accessed by outside (Netscaler redirection to server and port 8090), the application, when queried on the HTTPS port with URL such as https://public.domain.com/webapp, will returns following links:
http://public.domain.com:80/webapp/...

The link is generated using StrutsLinkTool setAction() method
https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.2/struts/StrutsLinkTool.html

It is creating issue with our forms treated as unsafe by certain browsers.
I am trying to figure out how I can get tomcat to return the publics https domain as base URL. I am trying to find out in the tomcat documentation how the base request URL is configured and if it can be customized?

I guess the proper solution would be to front tomcat with an apache server but I wonder if there is a simpler way to manage but modifying tomcat's server.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `secure="true"` to the `Connector`. As the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html) says:

> Set this attribute to `true` if you wish to have calls to `request.isSecure()` to return `true` for requests received by this Connector. You would want this on an SSL Connector or a **non SSL connector that is receiving data from a SSL accelerator**, like a crypto card, an SSL appliance or even a webserver. The default value is `false`.

Since your Netscaler is handling the SSL encryption and forwarding the requests un-encrypted to Tomcat, it acts as the "SSL accelerator".

The result will be that generated URLs with use `https:`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see a difference after setting the secure="true" attribute. It returns the same URL and it seems the issue is with something else

Comment: @Jako Well, since we don't know how the URL was built, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: It is built with Velocity StrutsLinkTool.setAction method. It is interesting that after changing the configuration as per your advice, I still get the warnings in the page inspector. The form, however, can be submitted on the browsers (Safari, IE 11) that were giving trouble before. Thanks!